# Write columns from different txt files using shell

Tags: linux, shell

I'm in trouble trying to write a shell script to generate a txt file
that will contains one column from one txt file, and other column from
a different txt file.

Could anyone help me please?

thanks.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way if you need to parse different columns from different input files :

```
paste <(cut -d " " -f1 file1) <(cut -d " " -f2 file2)
```

Or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
paste <(awk -F, '{print $1}' file1) <(awk -F, '{print $2}' file2)
```

Your question is a bit vague, so I make the assumption that the fields are delimited by a space for `cut` and a `,` in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `join` command. Look this [description](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_join.htm)

Comment: `join` is the right tool when you have a common field, not sure that was the case here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are joining entire lines from `file1` and `file2`, use `paste`:

```
% cat file1 
A
B
C
% cat file2 
1
2
3
% paste file1 file2 
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

Now, if you have columns in each file (in this example delimited by comma), to join `file1.col1` and `file2.col2`, where

```
% cat file1 
A,***
B,***
C,***
% cat file2 
***,1
***,2
***,3
```

do

```
%paste  <(cut -d "," -f1 file1)  <(cut -d "," -f2 file2)
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

Comment: OP asked files with multiple columns

Comment: @sputnick: That was my interpretation, too, but re-reading now, I see that it's really ambiguous. It's clear that the result file is supposed to have two columns, and that the two columns come from different source-files, but IMHO it's not clear whether those source-files each have multiple columns.

Comment: Yes, true. Hard to know =)

Comment: You got it right amphibient, I have two different files with 3 columns in each one, delimeted by " ". But it doesn't work here( yeah, I've changed comma for " ") =X. Syntax error: "(" unexpected
I've tried without "()", but doesn't work too.
I'm sorry, I'm beginning with shell...